# Working with dotnet and angular2

Tags: html, asp.net, angular

I have recently integrated a boostrap admin template (based on Angular2) in an asp project (here is the [repo](https://github.com/FacundoGFlores/Angular2_ASPCORE))

The thing is: when I am running `tsc`, all files compile well, but if I change `html` files, if the web browser (let say firefox) opened the project previously, the page never change, but if I open a new web browser (let say chrome) I can see the change. Now, if I change an `html` again, neither one can detect new changes in `html` files.

I think it is `dotnet` configuration, because I used the bootstrap angular template which is set up with npm lite server, and it has not any problems (I mean: change `.ts` files, `.html` files and it refresh always well)

To reproduce the problem, these are the steps:

1. npm install
2. dotnet restore
3. dotnet run
4. go to /pages/login <- It displays everything ok
5. edit `login.component.ts`: `template: <h1> Hello!</h1>`
6. go to /pages/login <- It keeps showing the login form
7. go to /pages/login (google-chrome) <- It shows the change
8. edit `login.component.ts`: `template: <h1> Hello World!</h1>`
9. go to /pages/login (google-chrome) <- It only shows Hello!

Comment: Ya..you're probably cached..

Comment: Where can I change it?

Comment: Your browser has it cached.  Hard refresh or get a chrome plugin like Cache Killer.

Comment: Yup, but I mean, why it only happens when I run the app from `dotnet`? If I run an standalone angular2 app, it is never cached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `asp` app were caching the pages, so I changed the `web.config`

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store" />
            <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
            <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```